# MySQL multitable SELECT query

Tags: mysql

Say you have 3 tables..

```
articles(id,id_cat)
categories(id)
messages(id,id_cat,id_article)
```

..where `articles` is related with `categories` and `messages` can be related either with `articles` or `categories` (a user can post a message in a category or in a article)

In a hypothetical current category `id=55`, Which query could i perform to list all messages posted in the current category and in articles belonging to current category?

**-- UNION SOLUTION --**

Poodlehat suggests the use UNION, which for this particular problem would be:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT m.id FROM messages AS m INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id=m.id_cat 
WHERE m.id_cat=55) 
UNION 
(SELECT m.id FROM messages AS m INNER JOIN articles AS a ON a.id=m.id_article 
WHERE a.id_cat=55)
) AS foo
```

**----**

Now, is there any way of doing this **without UNION**?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well, can you make the assumption that only one of id_cat or id_article is set and the other is NULL?

Comment: Yes, always one of them is set and the other is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id    
FROM messages m 
WHERE m.id_cat=55
union 
SELECT m.id 
FROM messages m, articles a 
WHERE a.id_cat=55
AND m.id_article=a.id
```

Doing it without a union, hmm, now you are challenging me... see if this works

```
SELECT m.id 
FROM messages m LEFT OUTER JOIN articles a ON m.id_article=a.id
WHERE m.id_cat=55 OR a.id_cat=55
```

Comment: What about the data from message table?

Comment: In a category=55, i'm looking to get all messages that: 1) are related to category 55 2) are related to articles that are related to category 55

Comment: I'm wondering if you do it without a union and then run an "explain" how different the optimizer results would be.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ::

```
Select * from 
messages m 
inner join categories c on (m.id_cat=c.id)
inner join article a on (c.id=a.id_cat)
where m.id_cat=55
```

Comment: This would filter only for messages with a category of 55, he wants all messages / articles with a `category id of 55`.

Comment: @JonH: I think it doesn't matter, because if we remove the where clause the number of rows returned will be same, and three columns (a.id_cat, c.id, m.id_cat) will have the same value, Then we are restricting to only category_id which is equal to 55, which hence doesn't depend on any particular column

Comment: The results might be correct, but when a programmer reads your code he sees that you are filtering on a messages table rather then an entire category.

Comment: Sashi, that and the fact that you explicitly use (*) in your select statement.  You filter incorrectly and you also list columns of the table messages when the user wants to see articles / messages.  All are part of good programming practices and clearly define what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Also, your statement assumes that the message is associated with an article by using an inner join, which the poster said it might not be (It might only be in a category without an article attached)